# Android Installs Not Showing on Facebook Developer Insights

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have an iOS and Android phone application that also has a Facebook application which enables users to share information. Every time someone downloads the application my analytics should show installs both iOS and Android, unfortunately it is just iOS, I'm not sure how to get it to  register the Android installs, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do, just from looking at the documentation, please check there next time. Here is what you need to do:

On your very first `Activity` add the following to your onCreate, As you can see below it requires a context and maybe the application ID.

```
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, yourAppIdHere);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AppEventsLogger/